# Xunit - how to have a cleanup being run after EVERY iteration of parametrized test?

Tags: c#, xunit

I have this question because I coudn't find an answer to this specific problem. I have some tests in Xunit, and these tests are parametrized. I want cleanup to run after EVERY single test iteration, not just once per test case.

```
public class UnitTest: TestsBase
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(BrowserType.Chrome)]
    [InlineData(BrowserType.Edge)]
    [InlineData(BrowserType.Firefox)]
    public void Test1(BrowserType browserType)
    {
    //do something
    }

public abstract class TestsBase : IDisposable
{
   
    public async void Dispose()
    {
        //Cleanup
    }
}
```

Everything works fine here, excep cleanup runs after the entire Test1 runs (all 3 browsers) and I dont know how to make it run after every iteration (inline data)

Comment: Can you switch away from inheritance? At least for the components you need cleaned up?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If the components you need to dispose are "has-a" related to your test, you can actively dispose and recreate them as you need. As is, it's a "is-a" relation which prevents you from doing exactly that.

Comment: Or ... why not create TheoryData with all resources that need to be call-specific? Then a fresh instance would be passed to the test with each test case in the theory. If you could elaborate a little on what exactly you need disposed, we could maybe come up with better suited ideas.

Comment: Well in my case each test iteration creates some database entry and I need to either delete that entry after each iteration or 
each iteration should add entry id to some list and clean method should iterate through that list id's to delete all entries from database. 

Something like that.

Comment: Well, there would be several solutions to this. You could fire up separate dbs for each browser. You could use tools like https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn. ... just to name two. You are not the first with that exact problem :D